# Change an image to text via CSS for printing?

Tags: css, image, text, header, printing

Lets say I have a header banner on a webpage I'm about to print.  Instead of wasting someone's ink printing the entire block of the image, is there a way via css to replace the image with text of H1 size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could put an `h1` element and an image in the same place in the source, and have the image CSS `display:none` for print media, and have the `h1` set to `display:none` for screen media.

Answer (score 10):

I usually just add the following to my style sheet:

```
.nodisplay
{
    display: none;
}

@media print {
    * {
        background-color: white !important;
        background-image: none !important;
    }
    .noprint
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

And then assign the **noprint** class to elements which shouldn't be printed:

```
<div class="noprint">

</div>
```

And for your example, something like the following should work:

```
<img src="logo.png" class="noprint" ...>
<h1 class="nodisplay">Text Logo</h1>
```

Answer (score 5):

Bryan, typically on things like logos I use image replacement for the graphic anyway so the logo itself is really in an H1 tag. Then in my print style sheet. I do something like this...

```
h1#logo a, h1#home-logo{
    text-indent: 0 !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    font-size: 1.2em !important;
    display: block !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: black !important;
}
```

Which removes the image replacement and shows the text. Make sure of course that you call this stylesheet separately using `media="print"`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Adam's solution: If your text is fixed ("head banner was there" not "ad for such and such was there"), you can use [:before or :after pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after) to insert text instead of having the text pre-inserted in the HTML.

I makes your HTML lighter if you are replacing many images with the same text.

I have to say that I dislike this CSS feature, but it is there if you want to use it.